# regular expression to tokenize string

Tags: java, regex, serialization

I have a serialized object that looks like this (not including inverted commas):

> 'key1:value1,key2:value2,key3:value3'

It could also look like this:

> 'key1:value1,key3:value3'

OR

> 'key1:value1'

OR

> '' (it could be empty)

At this point i have this token-izing logic break up this string (which is a tad bit verbose). Is there a single regular expression that can help me extract values for a given key (or return null) given any of the above strings?

Comment: What sort of values are in `value`? If text strings, for example, any straightforward solution depending on `:` and `,` need to be not-so-straightforward after all.

Comment: value will not contain "," or ":" as those are pre-decided delimiter strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keyword matching is straight-forward if you know exact boundaries. In this case, you have single apostrophes as string boundaries and a comma as a separator. So, this is the regex to match a value for a given key (based on your input example):

```
(?<=key1\:).+?(?=,|'|$) --> finds 3 "value1" matches
(?<=key2\:).+?(?=,|'|$) --> finds 1 "value2" match
(?<=key3\:).+?(?=,|'|$) --> finds 2 "value3" matches
(?<=key4\:).+?(?=,|'|$) --> no match
```

Comment: exact boundaries are not known. I just added inverted commas in the above post but the actual strings done have the inverted commas. Would the above expressions work in that case too?

Comment: I just changed your regex to (?<=key1\:).+?(?=,|$) for it to work for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess all you need is to find key/value pairs:

The simplest regex you can use is:

```
([^:,]+):([^:,]+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eK8tH8/1).

This will match a key in `$1` and a value in `$2`. Simple enough.

Now you could introduce variations if you want to:

```
(\w+):(.+?)(?=,|$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eK8tH8/2).

This one ensures the key only contains alphanumeric characters and underscores, and makes sure the value either ends with a comma or at the end of the string. Hopefully you get the point.

Comment: Thanks Lucas. This looks good. Just another quick question. So i am using (key1):(.+?)(?=,|$) to search and get key1:value1. Can i change the regex in such a way that when i query for say 'key1', i am returned just value1 (or nothing if key1 was not found).

At this point, because i am returned key1:value1 i still need that extra step to tokenize and extract value1.

Comment: @N.M. that's what capture groups are for. You get the value in the capture group number 2. but if you really want to hardcode the key value in the regex, you can just do: `(?<=key1:).+?(?=,|$)` but I discourage that, go the general-purpose way.

Answer (score 0):

### Use Ruby [String#Split](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/String.html#method-i-split)

Regular expression engines vary a lot by language, and since you didn't tag your question with one, I'm giving you a simple Ruby solution. The following will split your string on either a colon or a comma:

```
'key1:value1,key2:value2,key3:value3'.split /:|,/
#=> ["key1", "value1", "key2", "value2", "key3", "value3"]
```

Comment: sorry, should've mentioned.I need to do this in a java code.